# Wget - Downloading lots of files recursively is taking a long time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download, wget

Currently I am trying to download a large dataset (200k+ of large images) Its all stored on google cloud. The authors provide a wget script to download it:

```
wget -r -N -c -np --user username --ask-password https://alpha.physionet.org/files/mimic-cxr/2.0.0/
```

Now it downloads etc, but its been 2 days and its still going and I don't know how long its going to take. AFAIK its downloading each file individually. is there a way for me to download it in parallel?

EDIT: I don't have sudo access to the machine doing the downloading. I just have user access.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is a great tool but it is not designed to be efficient for downloading 200K files.

You can either wait for it to finish or find another tool that does parallel downloads provided that you have a fast Internet connection to support parallel downloads which might decrease the time by half over `wget`.

Since the source is an HTTPS web server, there really is not much you can do to speed this up besides downloading two to four files in parallel. Depending on your Internet speed, distance to the source server, you might not achieve any improvement with parallel downloads.

Note: You do not specify what you are downloading onto. If the destination is a Compute Engine VM, and you picked a tiny one (f1-micro) you may be resource limited. For any hi-speed data transfer pick at least an n1 instance size.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the urls then use the good old [httrack](https://www.httrack.com) website copier to download files in parallel:

```
httrack -v -w https://user:password@example.com/
```

Default is 8 parallel connections but you can use `cN` option to increase it.

If the files are large you can use `aria2c` this will download single file with multiple threads:

```
aria2c -x 16 url
```

You could find out if the files are store in GCS, if so then you can just use

```
gsutil -m <src> <destination>
```

This will download files in multithreaded mode

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the updated official MIMIC-CXR https://mimic-cxr.mit.edu/about/download/[downloads page.](https://mimic-cxr.mit.edu/about/download/)

There you'll find the info how to download via `wget` (locally) and `gsutil` (Google Cloud Storage)

Comment: Hi there! Links are encouraged, but please always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.